# Dynamic cloud tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tag-cloud

does anyone know of a jquery cloud tag plugin that will let me dynamically add tags. All the ones I've seen so far are based on a static  list and need to be destroyed and recreated to add or remove tags. Im looking for something more seamless.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on storing the tags for future use you could use something like this:

[JQuery-Powered cloud with PHP and JSON](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-jquery-powered-tag-cloud/)

That would give you the storage you want and it wouldn't take much more code to add a input box and a insert mysql query to add more.

The other alternative is to use something more like this:

[DynaCloud](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/dynacloud-a-dynamic-javascript-tag-keyword-cloud-with-jquery.html)

DynaCloud works by taking the id's and classes from elements on the webpage you have selected for "tagging" and then adds them to the cloud container

Hope that helps with finding your answer